# ARRIS CM820S modem and WiFi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, modem, wifi-configuration

this if my first post on this stack!

I've recently moved in a flat to see an Arris CM820S modem, which is working fine when i connect it directly to the PC using standard RJ45 cable, which is the only output this modem has. Btw, by 'fine', i mean i can access the internet.

The problem is, i need WiFi.

So i've tried to put it together using my old router (TP-LINK TD-W8901G, has 4 RJ45 ports labeled from *1* to *4* and one RJ11 port labeled as *LINE*) but as far as i understand, it needs RJ11 cable as an input (it works fine as a switch though).

Is it possible to setup WiFi using these two devices? If so, how, if not, what device should i buy.

**EDIT 1**

Alluding to Reg Edit's answer:

AFAIK i can't change Arris configuration because messing with configuration was blocked by my ISP (i should have posted it in the original question, i know).

As for option 2, will it be sufficent to configure TP-LINK like this?

- Disable DHCP
- Configure WiFi ssid / password
- Set router IP as one of Arris modem's available IPs
- Connect it to the modem using RJ45 cable connected to one of it's LAN ports

**EDIT 2**

I've just realized that by turning off DHCP i will be able to connect only one device to the internet since my ISP gave me one address and this modem will not work it out on it's own. And my router doesn't support access point mode AFAIK, so it leaves me with option 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can do this. I just [googled your Arris device](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GCEU_en-gb&ei=NDAGX9S1B-uclwTe5ZzgDA&q=Arris%20CM820S%20%22modem%20mode%22&oq=Arris%20CM820S%20%22modem%20mode%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIICCEQFhAdEB46BwgAEEcQsAM6BggAEBYQHlCAa1iGgQFgv4QBaAJwAHgAgAGIAYgB_QiSAQQxMi4xmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpeg&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjUn53owr7qAhVrzoUKHd4yB8wQ4dUDCAw&uact=5), and there are several hits on "modem mode" for it. This is the first approach I'd recommend, as you can continue to use all your existing WIFI and router settings. You will need to download the Arris user manual if you don't already have it.

OPTION 1: use modem mode

- Switch the Arris into Modem Mode, and
- Connect your TP-LINK router to the Arris to act as the router and WIFI access point in the same way your used to using it.

OPTION 2: use TP-LINK as an access point

For this you will need your TP-LINK user manual, and the TP-LINK will need to support being switched into access point mode. So check that first. If the answer is no, you will not be able to use option 2.

- Keep the Arris as it is,
- Configure the TP-LINK to act as an access point, and
- Connect the TP-LINK to the Arris to act as your WIFI access point.

OPTION 3 - purchase a WIFI access point

This is essentially the same as option 2; if your TP-LINK can't be configured to act as an access point, you can purchase a dedicated access point and connect that to the Arris instead.